# Problems with Terminal and Jekyll commands, e.g. `jekyll help`

Tags: terminal, jekyll

I'm a bit of a newbie to using Terminal, but would like to get a site up and running using Jekyll. I have followed the steps here and have something working: http://www.andrewmunsell.com/tutorials/jekyll-by-example/index.html

Terminal seems to be behaving strangely though. For example, when I type `jekyll help`, I get the following message displaying, and repeating itself lots of times. I then don't seem to have the ability to type anything else into Terminal.

```
NAME:

jekyll

DESCRIPTION:

Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby

COMMANDS:

build                Build your site                
default                             
docs                 Launch local server with docs for Jekyll v1.1.2        
doctor               Search site and print specific deprecation
warnings                
help                 Display global or [command] help documentation.        
import               Import your old blog to Jekyll         
new                  Creates a new Jekyll site scaffold in PATH             
serve                Serve your site locally                

ALIASES:

hyde                 doctor   
server               serve   

GLOBAL OPTIONS:

-s, --source [DIR] 
    Source directory (defaults to ./)

-d, --destination [DIR] 
    Destination directory (defaults to ./_site)

--safe 
    Safe mode (defaults to false)

-p, --plugins PLUGINS_DIR1[,PLUGINS_DIR2[,...]] 
    Plugins directory (defaults to ./_plugins)

--layouts 
    Layouts directory (defaults to ./_layouts)

-h, --help 
    Display help documentation

-v, --version 
    Display version information

-t, --trace 
    Display backtrace when an error occurs

~
~
(END)
```

Could there be something wrong with my setup that is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry! `jekyll help` is using a program called [`less`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm) which is a "paginator". It enables you to read a big file (in this case, Jekyll's help text).

You can go up and down by using `j` and `k`. To quit, type `q`.

Good luck and keep on learning. :)

Comment: Agarie, thank you so much. I knew it would be something simple that I would have missed.